# KeyStoneJs hangs after starting on Redat7.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

KeyStoneJS hangs after starting i.e. It doesn't do anything. It doesn't prints "KeyStone started port no xxxx"

```
Environment :- Redhat 7.1
NodeJs version :- v7.2.0
MongoDB community verion :- 3.2
```

So it is not that i didn't debug anything it. To get more insight, i enabled debug logs for keystoneJS.

Here is output of command :- 
    
DEBUG=keystone:* node keystone.js

```
keystone:core:mount mount exported  +0ms
  keystone:core:init initializing app +1s
  keystone:core:options settings options +1ms
  keystone:core:options setting session for auth +1ms
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> ~/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (~/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/index.js:3:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (~/CEC/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/index.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
  keystone:core:importer importing  ./views +232ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +1ms
  keystone:core:importer importing  ./views/admin +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +1ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +1ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +0ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +34ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +19ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +17ms
  keystone:core:importer recur +188ms
  keystone:core:options setting nav +0ms
  keystone:core:initNav init nav +1ms
  keystone:core:start mount the express app +25ms
  keystone:core:mount mounting +2ms
  keystone:core:mount setting DB URI to : mongodb://localhost/test +0ms
  keystone:core:mount using mongo for session store +0ms
  keystone:core:mount adding request logger +80ms
  keystone:core:mount adding file limit +1ms
  keystone:core:mount enabling frame guard +16ms
  keystone:core:mount adding keystone routes to express app +0ms
  keystone:core:routes setting keystone Admin Route +4ms
configuring app routes
  keystone:core:mount connecting to mongo +26ms
```

1) Very first thing which came in mind is MongoDB is not started OR WORKING , but to precise mongodb is started & working.

2) I have installed Robomongo to see if my local database can be connected. And i am able to see my database

3) As this is SELinux i have followed steps to  in /etc/selinux/config SELINUX=disabled . And restarted my system. 
Here is Output as soon as i started my mongod.

```
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21353 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=pbany1gc.ott.ciena.com
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.11
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-12-08T11:07:11.832-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-12-08T11:07:11.866-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-12-08T11:07:11.866-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=36G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running on a NUMA machine.
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          We suggest launching mongod like this to avoid performance problems:
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **              numactl --interleave=all mongod [other options]
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-12-08T11:07:12.023-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-12-08T11:07:12.024-0500 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-12-08T11:07:12.024-0500 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-12-08T11:07:12.025-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-12-08T11:07:34.616-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48696 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.618-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48697 #2 (2 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.620-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48698 #3 (3 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.629-0500 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:48697 (2 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.633-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48699 #4 (3 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.656-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48700 #5 (4 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.656-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48701 #6 (5 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.656-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48702 #7 (6 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48703 #8 (7 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48704 #9 (8 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48705 #10 (9 connections now open)
2016-12-08T11:07:34.657-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48706 #11 (10 connections now open)
```

Any help to debug further or any suggestions to fix doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I wrote this mongoose code but it is not doing anything no connection is done. var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});

exports.test = function(req,res) {
  res.render('test');
};
~

Comment: No output of above commented it keeps on waiting for connection

Comment: Problems is there with Mongoose. On my machine Mongoose is not able to connect to MongoDB which is causing a trouble. Raised issue in Mongoose no reply yet. But problem is narrowed down. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Problem is there with Mongoose. 
   On my machine Mongoose is not able to connect to MongoDB which was causing issue. 
   Raised issue in Mongoose no reply yet. But problem is being narrowed down.